# Propagating exception in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a simple actor hierarchy which looks as following:

```
root
  |
   -- parent1
  |   |
  |    -- child1_1
  |   |
  |    -- child1_2
  |
   -- parent2
      |
       -- child2_1
      |
       -- child2_2
```

`root` implements a `supervisorStrategy` handling various exceptions.
If an unhandled exception occurs in `parent1` or `parent2` then `supervisorStrategy` is reached and handling is done appropriately.
If an unhandled exception occurs in any of the children then I just get `[ERROR] akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy` and thats it.

How can I get any unhandled error in the hierarchy to propagate upward and reach the `root` where it would be handled?

Do I need to handle supervision and add `Escalate` to each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default supervision strategy is to **restart** child actor if the exception is of the type of `Exception` (or its children).

When the supervisor strategy is not defined for an actor the following exceptions are handled by default:

> ActorInitializationException will stop the failing child actor
>
> ActorKilledException will stop the failing child actor
>
> DeathPactException will stop the failing child actor
>
> Exception will
>   restart the failing child actor
>
> Other types of Throwable will be escalated to parent actor

So yes, you need to add supervision strategy to each level in this case.

Example:

```
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.{Escalate, Restart, Resume, Stop}
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, OneForOneStrategy, Props}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class RootActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
      case _: Exception                => {
        log.info("Got exception in root")
        Escalate
      }
    }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "START_ROOT" =>
      log.info("Started root actor")
      val parentActor = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[ParentActor]))
      parentActor ! "START_PARENT"
  }
}

class ParentActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
      case _: Exception                => {
        log.info("Got exception in parent")
        Escalate
      }
    }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "START_PARENT" =>
      log.info("Started parent actor")
      val childActor = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[ChildActor]))
      childActor ! "START_CHILD"
  }
}

class ChildActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "START_CHILD" =>
      throw new Exception("Exception from CHILD ACTOR")
      log.info("Started child actor")
  }

  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
    log.info("Restarting child actor")
    super.preRestart(reason, message)
  }
}
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    val rootActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[RootActor]))
    rootActor ! "START_ROOT"

  }
}
```

In this case, exception from child actor will be escalated to root actor.